# Encrypting properties with "eyaml edit" without a private key?

Tags: puppet, encryption, hiera, yaml, public-key-encryption

I would like to use *eyaml edit* to edit my Puppet/Hiera configuration files.  My configuration files are a mixture of encrypted and plain text content.  I want to use *eyaml edit* to encrypt certain properties.  So initially my files will contain something like:

```
DEC::PKCS7[securepassword]!
```

and I understand when I save them via *eyaml edit* these properties will be encrypted.

I have the public key which my Puppet Enterprise Server uses but I do not have access to the private key (for security reasons).

Can I still use *eyaml edit* without a private key?

I only want to use it to encrypt properties.

I know I can invoke *eyaml encrypt* without a private key but I would rather not encrypt each property individually and I don't need to encrypt the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to use "eyaml edit" without the private key has been [added](https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml/pull/256/commits/bb23ad01c17bc1eafb80923b8439f637e2ece218) in the master branch in GitHub.

This is how I am currently using it.

First configure eyaml so that it knows where your public key is (as per [encrypt your data using hiera eyaml](https://puppet.com/blog/encrypt-your-data-using-hiera-eyaml)).

```
~/.eyaml/config.yaml

---
pkcs7_public_key: ‘/Users/myuser/keys/eyaml/public_key.pkcs7.pem’
```

Then install master branch version of eyaml using the specific_install gem.

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml
```

Now you should be able to edit your eyaml files so that encryption works but decryption is not attempted using either (**-d** or **--no-decrypt** flags) e.g.

```
eyaml edit -d test.eyaml
```